# I can't connect to Openvswitch from virtual box vm

Tags: virtualbox, openvswitch

I have an openvswitch which running on a virtual box vm and i have another virtual box vm which i want to connect it to the openvswitch.How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a "bridged adapter" on the VMs and bridge to tap ports on the OVS bridge.